# TypeError: must be real number, not gurobipy.LinExpr

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to use a function that determines the distance between two coordinates in my gurobi model. The function uses the Haversine Formula to determine distances between coordinates. The goal of my gurobi model is to find an x and y coordinate that minimize the distance between a couple of coordinates. The Problem I am facing is that the distance function does not accept GRB expressions.

The code that I am using looks as follows

```
from gurobipy import Model, GRB
from math import cos

def distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    p  = 0.017453292519943295     #Pi/180
    a = (0.5 - cos((lat2 - lat1) * p)/2 +
        cos(lat1 * p) * cos(lat2 * p) * (1 - cos((lon2 - lon1) * p))
         / 2)
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a)) 

# example customer location coordinates 
cuslat = [55.43, 55.57, 55.38]
cuslon = [9.84, 9.95, 9.85]

# create Model
m = Model('lat lon that min distance')

# create variables
lat = m.addVar(vtype = GRB.CONTINUOUS, name = 'lat')
lon = m.addVar(vtype = GRB.CONTINUOUS, name = 'lon')


# set Objective
m.setObjective(distance(lat,lon,cuslat[0],cuslon[0]),GRB.MINIMIZE)

# set constraints 

m.optimize()
```

and the error I get from running this code is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runme.py", line 24, in <module>
    m.setObjective(distance(lat,lon,cuslat[0],cuslon[0]),GRB.MINIMIZE)
  File "runme.py", line 6, in distance
    a = (0.5 - cos((lat2 - lat1) * p)/2 +
TypeError: must be real number, not gurobipy.LinExpr
```

PS. I am new to posting question on Stackoverflow so I hope I formulated my question clearly enough

Comment: Could you add the full error stacktrace? There is valueable information in there

Comment: I can reproduce it, and I have edited the question to include the trace.

Answer (score 0):

The trace points at the `cos` function, and looking at your code

```
def distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    p  = 0.017453292519943295     #Pi/180
    a = (0.5 - cos((lat2 - lat1) * p)/2 +
```

it looks like you plug instances of `gurobipy.Var` through `lat1` and `lon1` into this function to formulate your objective function.  This will not work because

- the Python `cos` function will not know what to do with the `gurobipy.LinExpr` object produced by `lat2 - lat1` (hence the error message), and
- Gurobi supports only linear, piecewise linear, and quadratic objective functions (see also [product overview](http://www.gurobi.com/products/features-benefits)).

You could try to formulate your objective function as a piecewise linear function through the [`Model.setPWLObj()`](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_model_setpwlobj.html) function.